# Unable to install Brother MFC7460DN Network Printer

Tags: drivers, printing, networking

I am unable to install my network printer in Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit, as the driver is not available in the repository.

I am using Brother MFC7460DN. Any help would be appreciate it.

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Brother does not supply a 64bit package, you will need to use the 32bit compatibility library to install the available 32bit package.

First you need to download the cupswrapper *MFC7460DN* deb package from the [brother website](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#MFC-7460DN) to your `~/Downloads` folder

Also install package the `ia32-libs` that you should find in either synaptic manager or software center.

#### [ia32-libs](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ia32-libs) [image: Install ia32-libs]

Reach for you terminal and install the deb package you downloaded

```
sudo dpkg  -i  --force-all packagefilename.deb
```

Open Natty dash and find `printing` - you will then be able to find your network printer via its IP address.